# Converting _without and _findWhere from underscore to ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js

I have a student participation page that I provide for my students. I currently remove students by utilizing underscore by finding an id and simply removing that student based on the id. How do I go about implementing what I have below in ES6? I would appreciate any advice and or pointers.

```
var students = [{firstname: 'Jon', id: 99}, {firstname: 'Bob', id: 22}]
students = _.without(students, _.findWhere(students, {
  id: 99
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple filter

```js
var students = [{firstname: 'Jon', id: 99}, {firstname: 'Bob', id: 22}]
students = students.filter(e => e.id !== 99);
console.log(students);
```

Note that there's not too much ES6 involved here, `filter` is available since ES5. The only thing ES6 here is the arrow function.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
students = students.filter(student => student.id !== 99);
```